# Auto create Private Unlisted live stream Event on YouTube

Tags: youtube, applescript, youtube-livestreaming-api

Every week I have to broadcast live Private event on YouTube. All settings always is identical.

Is any way to automate process of creating live event on YouTube web page with script or any app?

Ideally would be to start live stream without go to YouTube page every time.

Wirecast and OBS does not have option to create event inside the app. Only XSplit does but is on Windows.

There is lots of settings on multiple pages I have to go through every time before you press "Start Stream" button. Just trying to simplify that process in one click. I am on mac.

Any ideas?